# Matching '|' (Vertical Line) Charachter in C++

Tags: c++, c, escaping

I am having a great deal of difficulty matching strings that contain a '|' (ascii 124) character in c++. In the following code method, each time it runs it always matches to the last if statement:

```
if (strComp == "D|A" || "D|M" || "A|D" || "M|D") {c = "010101";}
```

I have tried escaping the '|' symbol with '\|' which did not work. Surprisingly I have found little information on this issue when searched around. Is there just something else wrong with my code that I am overlooking? It is a normal ascii character, part of me thinks that this should be way easier...

```
string Code::comp(string strComp) {
string a = "0";
string c = "000000";

if (strComp.find('M') != -1) { a = "1"; }

if (strComp == "0") {c = "101010";}
if (strComp == "1") {c = "111111";}
if (strComp == "-1") {c = "111010";}
if (strComp == "D") {c = "001100";}
if (strComp == "A" || "M") {c = "110000";}
if (strComp == "!D") {c = "001101";}
if (strComp == "!A" || "!M") {c = "110001";}
if (strComp == "-D") {c = "001111";}
if (strComp == "-A" || "-M") {c = "110011";}
if (strComp == "D+1" || "1+D") {c = "011111";}
if (strComp == "A+1" || "M+1" || "1+A" || "1+M") {c = "110111";}
if (strComp == "D-1") {c = "001110";}
if (strComp == "A-1" || "M-1") {c = "110010";}
if (strComp == "D+A" || "D+M" || "A+D" || "M+D") {c = "000010";}
if (strComp == "D-A" || "D-M") {c = "010011";}
if (strComp == "A-D" || "M-D") {c = "000111";}
if (strComp == "D&A" || "D&M" || "A&D" || "M&D") {c = "000000";}
if (strComp == "D|A" || "D|M" || "A|D" || "M|D") {c = "010101";} // This matches every time

return a+c;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!
Justin

Comment: That's not how C works. Check any introductory text book on language basics.

Comment: It looks to me like your code is trying to evaluate expressions of some kind via brute force – perhaps it makes more sense to try to parse the expressions and evaluate that way instead of via (essentially) a lookup table.

Comment: NB: A string constant is an expression all on it's own, and it evaluates true in a boolean context. Now take that and look up the order of operation precedence in c.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
strComp == "D|A" || "D|M"
```

you need:

```
strComp == "D|A" || strComp == "D|M"
```

as the expression `strComp == "D|A"` is evaluated before the `||` operator so you get `false || "D|M"` or `true || "D|M"` which is not what you want.

Comment: While your solution fixes the problem, your explanation is wrong.  `==` has higher precedence than `||`, so the equality happens first.

Comment: Ahh! 
I should have seen that.
Thank you!

Comment: Also, what the OP thinks is happening is not what IS happening.  It's not just matching the last one every time.  It's matching each and every one of the `if` checks that is using the `strcmp == "xx" || "yy"` structure.  It matches the last one last and since they all set c= to something...c is what it was last set to.  There's more mistakes here than just one :P

Comment: You may want to explain what `true || <string>` and `false || <string>` evaluates too.